# How to create one SQL view with different queries per column?

Tags: sql

How can I create an SQL view with the following output:

```
filteredCountTableOne | filteredCountTableTwo | ...
----------------------|-----------------------|----
123                   | 456                   | ...
```

Where

- `filteredCountTableOne = "select count(id) from tableOne where col = 'val'"`
- `filteredCountTableTwo = "select count(id) from tableTwo where anotherCol = 'anyVal'"`

Comment: Why not just issue 2 queries?  the data doesn't seem to be releated and it's from two unrelated tables it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply select the result of two derived tables,

```
select
 (select count(id) from tableOne where col = 'val') filteredCountTableOne,
 (select count(id) from tableTwo where anotherCol = 'anyVal') filteredCountTableTwo
```

Comment: Thank you Stu, this is exactly what I searched for!

Answer (score 0):

```
create view v_example
as
 select count(id)as filteredCountTableOne  from tableOne where col = 'val'
   cross join 
 select count(id)as filteredCountTableTwo from tableTwo where anotherCol = 'anyVal'
```

Most probably, you need something different. If so, please provide valid sample data and desired output

Comment: Thanks for the proposal Sergey - this ends in an SQL error for me, pointing to the cross join. However, the  response by Stu is exactly what I searched for.